# Batch table/Column update in powerdesigner reading from excel using vb script

Tags: powerdesigner

I am looking for developing a vb script which would extract all the table/columns from powerdesigner model to a excel file. After changing few properties I will be updating it to the model using vbscript. So I would like to know if there is any property of a column which can uniquely identify each column of a table. Example:- ROWID column in oracle

Does powerdesigner maintain unique id for each object created in PDM?

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) modelisation objects derive from `IdentifiedObject`, which has an `ObjectID` property, a GUID.